# Last version of GraphicsMagick for raspbian (Raspberry Pi 3)

Tags: c++, raspbian, raspberry-pi3, graphicsmagick

I want to use the GraphicsMagick++ library on a C++ project that I am working on in a Raspberry Pi 3 (Raspbian).

I have installed the package using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libgraphicsmagick++-dev
```

After playing a bit, I have found that the method Image::extent is not defined on Image.h header, while is is shown on the documentation.

Is there any newer version? How to install it?

Answer (score 1):

You can find all the packages related to libgraphicsmagick in debian on https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libgraphicsmagick

Comment: Whats the difference between these packages?
libgraphicsmagick++-q16-12, 
libgraphicsmagick++1-dev, 
libgraphicsmagick++3 ? Which one should I install to get the last version of the library?

Comment: They show you which versions are available in which debian releases. For an overview of releases, see https://www.debian.org/releases/ Raspbian in particular is available as wheezy (debian 7.x) and jessie (debian 8.x). The version of a given library is usually sticky for the the whole lifetime of a release. If you need a newer version, you should consider upgrading your entire operating system to a newer release (if available), or add a backports suite like https://backports.debian.org/Instructions/ (if available) , or (least preferred) install from source into /usr/local/ by hand.

Comment: The strange thing is that I am using the last Debian (8.x) and i have issued an "apt-get dist-upgrade", but the version library that is installed after running "apt-get install libgraphicsmagick++-dev" is "/usr/lib/GraphicsMagick-1.3.20" which is from August 16, 2014, and indeed does not have the "extent" methods as it was added on "1.3.21" version

Comment: Yes, it certainly looks like jessie ships 1.3.20. The upcoming "stretch" release (debian 9.x?) will likely contain 1.3.25. As I already mentioned, stable debian (and thus raspbian) releases stay on a specific version and does not bring upgrades during the lifetime of the release. If you can't wait, and don't mind running a pre-beta OS, you can upgrade to "testing" aka "stretch" aka the upcoming debian 9.x release now already. Here's a random howto: https://linuxconfig.org/raspbian-gnu-linux-upgrade-from-jessie-to-raspbian-stretch-9

Comment: You can also set up apt pinning and pick & choose installation of stretch packages into a jessie installation, but it's quite unsupported and might bring in a whole slew of dependencies which would make your system a franken-stretch. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/59435/how-to-use-stretch-testing-packages